# cartan killing metric

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, smooth-manifolds

I know that we can define the killing form on a lie algebra. However, when going to the group manifold, does this give rise to a metric on the manifold? I thought that would be the case, but I cant find any useful literature how this works. Especially, I am confused since the Lie algebra seems to always be defined around the unity, but I guess on a group manifold one can use that we can always map any point to unity and thus also map the tangent space?

So Let's say I have a Lie group manifold parametrized by coordinates x0,x1,...,xn. How can I obtain the metric induced from the killing form?

Comment: The killing form is not always positive definite, so does not always give a Riemannian metric...

Comment: Danger: the Killing form $B$ on a nonsemisimple Lie group is degenerate, i.e. has vectors $v$ so that $B(v,w)=0$ for all $w$. So no hope of a metric. All of this is very standard in all of the textbooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any inner product on $\mathfrak{g}$ will give rise to a metric on $G$. More specifically, you can use a left trivialization of $TG$ to get a vector bundle isomorphism $TG\cong G\times\mathfrak{g}$. The latter bundle has a metric by virtue of the inner product on $\mathfrak{g}$.

The same construction will work if one instead uses the right trivialization.

Comment: So as I understand it, to phrase it differently, the left/right multiplication of a group element $a$ defines a mapping from $\mathfrak{g}$, the tangent space at the origin, to a tangent space at a point $a$, and via this we can define the inner product at the tangent space of $a$?

Btw, will the left/right construction give the same metric?

Comment: You are right, but I would prefer to say that the differential at $e$ of left (resp. right) multiplication by $a$ allows us to transfer an inner product on $\mathfrak{g}$ to the tangent space at $a$. No, in general, the metric will depend on the particular trivialization you have chosen.

Comment: Since the OP mentioned the Killing form, it would not be amiss to point out that if the inner product on $\mathfrak{g}$ is ad-invariant: $\langle[X,Y],Z\rangle = \langle X,[Y,Z]\rangle$, then the metric on $G$ will be bi-invariant, so that left- and right- trivialisations give rise to the same metric.

Comment: Yes, fair enough.

Comment: @JoséFigueroa-O'Farrill: Are there any statements regarding whether taking the trace in another representation will give rise to the same metric? I tried this on SL(2,R) and both the defining and adjoint representations gave the same killing form (up to an overall constant)

Comment: If the Lie algebra is simple, then there is up to homothety one invariant inner product.  Hence it is not surprising that you should get the same inner product up to a multiples in SL(2,R).